# Java + MySQL error on Query

Tags: java, mysql

I'm programming Java, and Eclipse is showing me this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''where Name=''and Password=''' at line 1
```

I tried to fix the query but the error remains.Can you control if i write the query correctly?

-Connection() is a class that i use to connect into the database,in this class i' ve all connection method.I create this class to not repeat the connection in all classes.But this is not the error.

`text1,2,3` are textboxes. I want to get the tablename via textbox 3.

```
String name = text1.getText();

String password = text2.getText();

String employment = text3.getText();

try {

ResultSet rs = Connection.Creation().executeQuery("select * from '" + employment +
 "'where Name='" + name + "'and Password='" + password + "'");
}
catch
{
//something here
}
```

Comment: You're very vulnerable for SQL-Injection this way.

Comment: You are using the value of the Java string `employment` to name your table. Is that what you intended?

Comment: is exactly, I want to explore the table given as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this 

MySQL Identifiers

The identifier quote character is the backtick ("`") in MySQL.

ResultSet rs = Connection.Creation().executeQuery("select * from `" + employment +
 "` where Name='" + name + "'and Password='" + password + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ResultSet rs = Connection.Creation().executeQuery("
select * from " + employment + " where Name='" + name + "' and Password='" + password + "'");
```

The from shouldn't have ' '.

As I said in comment, you're very vulnerable for SQL-Injection this way.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please copy it again and display me the error you get in catch.

Comment: the same error.. the full display error is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where Name='' and Password=''' at line 1